# Invalid format specifier while using a value stored in a variable?

Tags: python

I have a program that prints some stuff in columns:

```py
print("{: <7}{: <15}{: <75}{: <25}".format(sno, variable[1], variable[2], variable[3]))
```

Sometimes the values are too large or somewhat small, so I want to dynamically assign the spaces to the specific columns. So I loop through the stuff and get the maximum length of the string. Then I want to assign it to the number of spaces like this:

```py
max = 10 #or any other integer which gets calculated dynamically.
print("{: <7}{: <15}{: <max}{: <25}".format(sno, variable[1], variable[2], variable[3]))
```

But this line gives me a `ValueError: Invalid format specifier` Error.
Is there a better way to do this or do I have to hard-code the integer there?

Comment: It’s not a good idea to use `max` as a variable name as it’s overwriting the built in function.

Comment: Ok, That isn't a problem because I used that variable just to show an example here, I have other variable names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to treat `max` as a variable, but it is nothing more than a string, which is why python tries to
recognize it as a format-specifier and fails.

You'd have to do it like this:

```
max = 10 #or any other integer which gets calculated dynamically.
format_str = '{: <7}{: <15}{: <' + str(max) + '}{: <25}'
print(format_str.format(sno, variable[1], variable[2], variable[3]))
```

Notice that I'm constructing the format-string with the *value* of `max`, not just the string `"max"`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use python's (version >= 3.6.x) `f-String` formatting:

```
max = 10
print(f"{sno: <7}{variable[1]: <15}{variable[2]: <{max}}{variable[3]: <25}")
```

[PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)